# Batch files vs. BCP Commands

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, bcp

Difference between batch files and BCP Commands???

As per my knowledge BCP(Bulk copy program) is used to load the data from flat files to database in a fast way and vice versa and batch files are used to copy the files from one location to other location, to create new directories..etc using MS-Dos commands.

Can i get exact difference between  Batch files and BCP Commands??

Thanks

Venaikat

Comment: You do work with `MS-DOS`?

Comment: Yes, i worked with MS-Dos but only with basic commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files are to BCP as Java is to JavaScript

Comment: And how is Java to JavaScript?

Comment: so using BCP Commands we can create Batch files with .bat extension. Isn't it??

Comment: How did you get that from my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

BCP is a command line tool

Batch files allow you to script command line tools, to make them perform their various functions in a repetitive and reproducible way, without needing keyboard or mouse interaction.

Batch files are a general purpose programming scripting language that is interpreted, and so is slower than a compiled language, but batch scripts are generally much faster to develop a program/script to perform a task.  They also have limitations when compared to many compiled languages, with poison characters etc.